# VBA CODE to Verify Email Address Found in Outlook Global Address List

Tags: excel, vba, email

Problem Description

To remove Inactive (non existing )email accounts not found in global address list  before send email to list of available outlook email accounts in excel

Solution

Run sql Query to fetch Username or User Email id from Database

Step 1 :

Query 1 :

```
strSQL = "select distinct [User Email ID]  from dbo.vw_EmailRecipients_AT where Report_Catalog_ID in (" & rptid & ")"
```

or

Query 2 :

```
strSQL = "select distinct [User Name]  from dbo.vw_EmailRecipients_AT where Report_Catalog_ID in (" & rptid & ")"
```

Step 2 :

Call the Module to Copy retrieve Result Set to Excel Sheet

```
Sub Testemail()
    Dim rEmails As Range
    Dim rEmail As Range
    Dim oOL As Object

    Set oOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set rEmails = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report_Users").Range("A2:A" & Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each rEmail In rEmails
        rEmail.Offset(, 1) = ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP(rEmail.Value, oOL)
    Next rEmail

End Sub
```

Step 3 :

Resolve Display Name

```
Public Function ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP(sFromName, OLApp As Object) As String

    Dim oRecip As Object 'Outlook.Recipient
    Dim oEU As Object 'Outlook.ExchangeUser
    Dim oEDL As Object 'Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList

    Set oRecip = OLApp.Session.CreateRecipient(sFromName)
    oRecip.Resolve
    If oRecip.Resolved Then
        ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP = "Valid"
    Else
        ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP = "Not Valid"
    End If
End Function
```

Bug 1: If I Use Query 1 : The resultset will be abcdef@company.com where all the email id will be valid - WRONG_RESULT.

Bug 2: If I Use Query 2 : The resultset will be combination of UserName
like Rajan jha(rjhan) and contract employees will be Rajan jha (rjhan - Compnay1 is at Compnay2)

In this result the output with Rajanjha(rjahan), if the email account is found in GAL it will valid and if not found it will be Invalid email.For resultset like Rajan jha (rjhan - Compnay1 is at Compnay2) where even email account exist in GAL it result as invalid.

please guide me through to solve this problem

Comment: Without fully understanding he question, I believe the root problem is in some cases VBA does not feasibly retrieve GAL data. A VBA answer may involve looping the entire GAL. See here where an alternative solution through Redemption `RDOSession.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveName` is suggested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825214/excel-2007-format-of-email-address-from-outlook-2007

Comment: Thanks niton, As I checked in the link solution what is available is takes a long time to run. Regarding **RDOSession**. I need download Software. I have been not allowed use for commercial Purpose. Is there any other Choices to solve the problem. I am not specific to find email Accounts in GAL. If it is not found in local Address fine.

Comment: If you have given up on the GAL then one method of retrieving from Contacts is described here [How to get Email address from outlook contacts for the names listed in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45517263/how-to-get-email-address-from-outlook-contacts-for-the-names-listed-in-a-column)

Comment: Thanks Niton , As I saw link u provided in the comment help me Identify "local Contact not Updated with Address" , so I have to use `o.Session.AddressLists("Global Address List")`  only. But It takes to took much time to check if Condition for each Name in the Global Address Entry Name. But I cannot use `RDOSession` . But Why `Receipient.Resolve` is not accurately resolve for all email Accounts. Is there any other property forceful to resolve the receipient.

Comment: Thanks @niton for Support and helping to keep Consistency to work this problem. But I have solved problem for Email id of the Same Company Name.                                                                                                          ` Set oRecip = OLApp.Session.CreateRecipient(sFromName)
    oRecip.Resolve
    oRecipName = oRecip.Name

    If oRecip.Resolved And InStr(oRecipName, "@") = 0 Then
        ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP = "Valid"
    Else
        ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP = "Not Valid"
    End If `

Answer (score 3):

I have solved Problem by making small changes in Condition Checking of Intermediate Output.

```
Public Function ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP(sFromName, OLApp As Object) As String

    Dim oRecip As Object  'Outlook.Recipient

    Set oRecip = OLApp.Session.CreateRecipient(sFromName)
    oRecip.Resolve
    oRecipName = oRecip.Name

    If oRecip.Resolved And InStr(oRecipName, "@") = 0 Then
        ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP = "Valid"
    Else
        ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP = "Not Valid"
    End If

End Function
```

Here `oRecip.Resolve` is resolving Email Id of Active and Inactive Email ID Of
Same Company and `InStr(oRecipName, "@") = 0` plays key role to remove invalid email id.

Inactive Email  `oRecip.Resolve` will Resolve output to valid. But the output will be

> rajaanjha@company1.com

Here `InStr(oRecipName, "@") = 0` checks for `@` in the String and flag as Invalid Email  Id

Active Email  `oRecip.Resolve` will Resolve output to valid. But the output will be

> Rajan Kumar Jha     (First Middle Last Name) of User Email Id
>   Where `@` will not be in Intermediate String and it is Valid Email Id.

But I have problem Email ID like

> rajanjha@company2.com

Where Active Email ID's Company is not getting Resolved to User name which need to be Solved.

Comment: Fantastic, that's what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I concur with niton.  Instead of using VBA for this, and I am a huge fan of VBA, I would say grab the GAL using the methodology described in the URL below.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3590-outlook-export-gal-to-csv.html

I've tried VBA to download all data pertaining to all contacts in Outlook, with horrible consequences.  If you use the built-in controls, and follow the steps described above, you will get everything you need quickly and accurately.  If you try to develop your own custom VBA solution, you are totally on your own there...