# Application.Startup not called, event code triggers only when Visual Basic Editor is open

Tags: vba, outlook, vbe

Following Outlook VBA code is triggering only when the Visual Basic Editor is open.

I tried other events. All are working when VBA editor screen is open.

```vb
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
    Dim strattach As String
    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myitems As Outlook.Items
    Dim OLNS As Outlook.Folder
    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'Set OLNS = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'Set myInbox = OLNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myInbox = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Dim count As Integer
    count = myInbox.Items.count
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim MessageInfo
    Dim Result
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim i As String
    Dim mailsub As String
    'mailsub = Item.Subject
    mailsub = myInbox.Items.Item(count).Subject
    i = InStr(mailsub, "SC3")
    If i = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Dim ii As String
    Dim mailbody As String
    'mailbody = Item.Body
    mailbody = myInbox.Items.Item(count).Body
    ii = InStr(mailbody, "ERP")
    If ii = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Dim ttt As String
    'ttt = "http://company.com"
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute ttt
ExitNewItem:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitNewItem
End Sub
```

I used `Debug.Print` in `Application.Startup`. Sometimes it is not called and my code is not triggered.
When the `Application.Startup` Sub is called the code works.

Comment: Have you tried to run the code under the debugger attached? Does it work in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Debug.Print` method to track what is going in the code while the VBA editor is closed. Following that way you may find the cause of the problem.

Also I've noticed that you  iterate over all items in the folder:

```
mailsub = myInbox.Items.Item(count).Subject
i = InStr(mailsub, "SC3")
```

which is not really a good idea when dealing with the Outlook object model.

Instead, you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class.

You can read more about these methods in the following articles I wrote on the topic:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Please be sure to read [Stack Overflow's self-promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when referencing your own content.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I have used Debug.print in "Application Startup" Sub and it seems everytime whenever the Outlook is started the "Application Startup" sub is not getting called and it seems in those cases my program/code  is also not getting triggered.  Although sometimes during starting of Outlook Application the "Application Startup" Sub is getting called and that time also my programming/code is working.   It seems the problem with Loading of Outlook during starting Outlook Application.  if I restart , it is working again sometime.. Any idea please?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why your add-in may not be loaded at startup. There is a Windows environment variable called `VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS` which can enable to display Outlook and VSTO error messages when VSTO add-ins are being loaded. Also pay attention to possible exceptions at startup.

Comment: Thanks for your response again, can you please help me how to use Find, restrict syntax in VBA Outlook ( I have seen links given by you, but those were not of VBA)

Answer (score 0):

I've re-written your code and included code comments to explain the changes ... this must go into the `ThisOutlookSession` module.

As suggested by @Eugene Astafiev I have included a number of `Debug.Print` statements so you can see what has been happening when you open the Visual Basic Editor following a period of it being closed while Outlook is running.

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
    On Error GoTo errExit
    
    Debug.Print Now, "Email received"
    
    ' use Folder not the deprecated MAPIFolder
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    ' you do not need create an instance of Outlook ie with Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") ... you
    ' already have the Outlook.Application object available to you
    Set myInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    ' use Long not Integer for the count, overflow could happen if too many items for an Integer to hold
    Dim count As Long
    count = myInbox.Items.count
    Debug.Print Now, "Found " & count & " items"
    ' if no items found, exit as the newly received mail item may not be in the Inbox
    If count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim o As Object
    Set o = myInbox.Items.Item(count)
    ' check that the Item is a MailItem ... it doesn't have to be as you are working with the last item in the Inbox
    ' folder, not necessarily the newly received item
    If StrComp(TypeName(o), "MailItem", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then Exit Sub
    Debug.Print Now, "The item we are working with is a MailItem"
    
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim mailsub As String
    Set Msg = o
    mailsub = Msg.Subject
    If InStr(mailsub, "SC3") = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Debug.Print Now, "The subject includes 'SC3'"
    
    Dim mailbody As String
    mailbody = Msg.Body
    If InStr(mailbody, "ERP") = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Debug.Print Now, "The body includes 'ERP'"
    
    ' set the value for ttt before calling .ShellExecute
    'ttt = "http://company.com"
    'CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute ttt
    'Debug.Print Now, "ShellExecute performed"
    
    Exit Sub

errExit:
    Debug.Print Now, "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Replace(Err.Description, vbNewLine, ", ")
End Sub
```

If you are still having problems with the code not running until you open the VBE:

1. Check your settings allow macros to run ... in Outlook: File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Macro Settings ... ensure 'Notifications for all macros' is selected ... you can also select 'Enable all macros' but note the warning!
2. Try using the `Application_NewMailEx()` event handler instead of the `Application_NewMail()` event handler ... see the MS Docs for the pros and cons of each [NewMail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmail) and [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex)